# Sumar resultados de una columna de una tabla

Tags: php, html

quizás la forma de formular la pregunta no es la correcta, pero explico.

He creado una tabla en lo que muestro que la gente nos valorara con varias preguntas del 1 al 10, y esto se mostrara en la web con una tabla.

**Así tengo el asunto:**

```
<table id="encuesta" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="display:none">ID</th>
                <th style="min-width: 130px;" class="center2">Fecha encuesta</th>
                <th>La capacidad de respuesta</th>
                <th>Atención al cliente</th>
                <th>Resolución de problemas</th>
                <th>Calidad Servicio técnico</th>
                <th>Calidad de los equipos</th>
                <th>Como valorarias a Med-Apolo como empresa</th>
                <th style="min-width: 90px;">Nota media</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php
            $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT((en.fecha),'%d/%m/%Y') fechada, en.idencuesta, en.respuesta, en.atencion, en.problemas, en.mantenimiento, en.funcionalidad, en.valorar FROM encuesta AS en");
            foreach ($results as $encuesta){
              $suma = $encuesta['respuesta'] + $encuesta['atencion'] + $encuesta['problemas'] + $encuesta['mantenimiento'] + $encuesta['funcionalidad'] + $encuesta['valorar'];
              $total = $suma / 6;
              $totalisimo = number_format($total, 2, ',', ' ');
          ?>
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none;"><?php echo $encuesta['idencuesta']; ?></td>
                <td class="center2"><?php echo $encuesta['fechada']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $encuesta['respuesta']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $encuesta['atencion']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $encuesta['problemas']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $encuesta['mantenimiento']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $encuesta['funcionalidad']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $encuesta['valorar']; ?></td>
                <?php if ($totalisimo == 10) {
                  echo "<td style=\"background-color: rgba(53,247,8,0.29) !important;\">$totalisimo</td>";
                }else{
                  echo "<td>$totalisimo</td>";
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
          <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td class="myTD">Media: <?php echo number_format($totalCapacidad, 2, ',', ' ') ?></td>
              <td class="myTD">Media: <?php echo number_format($totalCapacidad2, 2, ',', ' ') ?></td>
              <td class="myTD">Media: <?php echo number_format($totalCapacidad3, 2, ',', ' ') ?></td>
              <td class="myTD">Media: <?php echo number_format($totalCapacidad5, 2, ',', ' ') ?></td>
              <td class="myTD">Media: <?php echo number_format($totalCapacidad6, 2, ',', ' ') ?></td>
              <td class="myTD">Media: <?php echo number_format($totalCapacidad7, 2, ',', ' ') ?></td>
              <td class="myTD">Media: AQUÍ QUIERO MOSTRAR EL TOTAL DE TODAS LAS MEDIAS Y SACAR LA MEDIA DE ESE TOTAL.</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

En la columna "nota media" es donde muestro la media de cada fila. Para eso cojo todos los resultados y le hago el calculo de este modo:

```
              $suma = $encuesta['respuesta'] + $encuesta['atencion'] + 
              $encuesta['problemas'] + $encuesta['mantenimiento'] + 
              $encuesta['funcionalidad'] + $encuesta['valorar'];
              $total = $suma / 6;
              $totalisimo = number_format($total, 2, ',', ' ');
              $totalMedia = $totalisimo;
```

Luego en el pie de la página saco la media de cada columna, que esto ya lo tengo.

Pero en la columna de "Nota media" al pie de página quiero mostrar la media de todas las medias de la columna "Nota media", pero no se como hacer este calculo.

Saludos

Comment: ¿Que es lo que no sabes hacer? ¿Calcular la media? Por que si has calculado otras 6 medias la formula de esta es igual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo crearía una variable contador y la iniciaría antes del foreach. Luego, para cada nota media, haría una variable llamada NotaMediaFinal donde iría calculando la media de las "notas medias" dividido entre el contador.

En tu caso y con mi comentario, el código quedaría así:

```
<table id="encuesta" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="display:none">ID</th>
            <th style="min-width: 130px;" class="center2">Fecha encuesta</th>
            <th>La capacidad de respuesta</th>
            <th>Atención al cliente</th>
            <th>Resolución de problemas</th>
            <th>Calidad Servicio técnico</th>
            <th>Calidad de los equipos</th>
            <th>Como valorarias a Med-Apolo como empresa</th>
            <th style="min-width: 90px;">Nota media</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
        $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT((en.fecha),'%d/%m/%Y') fechada, en.idencuesta, en.respuesta, en.atencion, en.problemas, en.mantenimiento, en.funcionalidad, en.valorar FROM encuesta AS en");
        $notaMediaFinal = 0;
        $contadorNotaMedia = 0;
        foreach ($results as $encuesta){
          $contadorNotaMedia += 1;
          $suma = $encuesta['respuesta'] + $encuesta['atencion'] + $encuesta['problemas'] + $encuesta['mantenimiento'] + $encuesta['funcionalidad'] + $encuesta['valorar'];
          $total = $suma / 6;
          $totalisimo = number_format($total, 2, ',', ' ');
          $notaMedia += $totalisimo;
          $notaMediaFinal = $notaMedia / $contadorNotaMedia;
      ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none;"><?php echo $encuesta['idencuesta']; ?></td>
            <td class="center2"><?php echo $encuesta['fechada']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $encuesta['respuesta']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $encuesta['atencion']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $encuesta['problemas']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $encuesta['mantenimiento']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $encuesta['funcionalidad']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $encuesta['valorar']; ?></td>
            <?php if ($totalisimo == 10) {
              echo "<td style=\"background-color: rgba(53,247,8,0.29) !important;\">$totalisimo</td>";
            }else{
              echo "<td>$totalisimo</td>";
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td class="myTD">Media: <?php echo number_format($totalCapacidad, 2, ',', ' ') ?></td>
          <td class="myTD">Media: <?php echo number_format($totalCapacidad2, 2, ',', ' ') ?></td>
          <td class="myTD">Media: <?php echo number_format($totalCapacidad3, 2, ',', ' ') ?></td>
          <td class="myTD">Media: <?php echo number_format($totalCapacidad5, 2, ',', ' ') ?></td>
          <td class="myTD">Media: <?php echo number_format($totalCapacidad6, 2, ',', ' ') ?></td>
          <td class="myTD">Media: <?php echo number_format($totalCapacidad7, 2, ',', ' ') ?></td>
          <td class="myTD">Media: <?php echo number_format($notaMediaFinal, 2, ',', ' ') ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Está sin probar debido que no estoy en tu entorno, pero pruebalo y me dices a ver.

Comment: En mi opinión sería mejor que el cálculo de la $notamediaFinal se hiciera fuera del foreach, ya que ademas de conseguir el mismo resultado, de esta manerá en el momento que lo haces las dos variables disponen de un valor final.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funciona a la perfección!

Answer (score 0):

Algo como:

```
<td class="myTD"> <?php echo number_format( ($totalCapacidad + $totalCapacidad2 + $totalCapacidad3 + $totalCapacidad5 + $totalCapacidad6 + $totalCapacidad7)/ 6 , 2, ',', ' ') ? </td>
```

Comment: Trata de explicar tu código y la manera en que resuelve la duda del OP. Mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) así te das una idea de las normas de la comunidad para dar respuestas de calidad y evitar que sean eliminadas.